# GridBagLayout cell size

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I am working on the layout of a program and have created a grid using GridBagLayout. The grid is filled with buttons (some buttons spanning over more than one cell). For the case where there is a button spanning a single cell:

Is there a way to make each cell within the grid the same size. I ask because right now the cell size of each column is being determined by the largest button in each column. How can I make sure this doesn't occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to make each cell within the grid the same size

Use a `GridLayout`.

You can always create a JPanel for the grid structure and then add the panel to the main panel that uses your GridBagLayout. You are not forced to use a single panel/layout for the entire frame.

Comment: I need to use gridbaglayout since there are some buttons within the panel which span over more than one cell.

Comment: Your requirement doesn't make sense, you want all the cells to be the same same, but complain that the largest button determines the size. Well what do you expect? If you choose the smallest button to be the size of every cell, then some text will be truncated on the largest button. Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem, because you verbal description is not very good. That is why I suggested multiple panels to achieve the layout.